# Are two unrelated questions always considered duplicates if one answer has a quote that addresses both questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Say that we have the following hypothetical question and answer on the site:

> **Q:** What race is Gandalf?
>
> **A:** In Letter 123, Tolkien wrote: "Gandalf and Saruman are Maiar."

A year later, another user asks this question:

> **Q:** What race is Saruman?

Is this second question a duplicate of the first because the other question has the answer in the quote from Tolkien, and the same quote could be used in the new one?

I ask because I've seen a number of questions closed as duplicates that basically boil down to this situation. What usually follows is a string of comments where people argue about if it's really a duplicate (often including sentiments like "How was I supposed to know to look at that question?").

I am aware that there are other options like editing the first to be a canonical question, but since that's not always practical or desirable, I want to focus on whether or not these two would be duplicates in their current form.

*This might have been addressed in previous meta topics, but since most of them are really "should this specific question have been closed as a duplicate?", I'm hoping to better understand our general duplicate policy without reference to any real question.*

Comment: "*And if the community agrees that there is enough of a distinction between the questions, or the OP can explain why the original question/answers don't cover the information they're looking for, then the question can be re-opened. Closing isn't permanent.*"; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/why-is-the-close-as-duplicate-policy-so-aggressive-and-should-we-change-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Pardon the irony of closing a question about duplicates as a duplicate ... I did at first copy-paste the first section of my answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/31394) into the answer box below, but then decided that this question really is a dupe of the existing (general) discussion of whether or not answers should make questions duplicates, with a +29 scoring answer from a CM.